# Scala: run an external command, and get both the Process and the stdout Stream[String]

Tags: scala

Scala provided a function to execute a command and get the stdout stream:

```
var lines = Seq("somecommand") lines_! //This returns the stdout as Stream[String]
```

And a function to get the process itself

```
var process = Seq("somecommand") run  //This returns the process
```

But is there a way to get both, and return them as a tuple inside a function? The external command I am executing has very long running time, and I am redirecting the stdout to an Enumerator using Enumerator.enumerate (play API). I also need to get the Process handler so that I can terminate it before it finishes.

Comment: Can'y you get stdout from the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
var p = Promise[java.io.InputStream]
var seq = Seq("somecommand")
var proc = Process(seq)
var process = proc run new ProcessIO(
  _.close(),
  (input: java.io.InputStream) => {
    p.completeWith(Future.successful(input))
  },
  _.close()
)

var r = Await.result(p.future, 10 seconds)
Future{
  process.exitValue();
  //...do some clean up stuff...
}
(process, r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to utilize a `ProcessLogger` in order to redirect stdout to your Enumerator directly, something like this:

```
 import scala.sys.process._

 val err = new StringBuilder 
 val enumerator = ...

 val proc = "<cmd>" run ProcessLogger(/* redirect stdout to enumerator */, 
                                      err append _)

 /* do something with proc */
```

The `ProcessLogger` will invokes its first argument, which is a function of type `String => Unit`, whenever a line becomes available.